# javascript getattribute type

Tags: javascript, object, onclick, getattribute

I try to get the attribute of an onclick event, so I try:

```
var onclickevent = btn.getAttribute("onclick");
alert(onclickevent);
```

this works fine, but then I tried:

```
var onclickevent = btn.getAttribute("onclick");
var subst = onclickevent.substring(2,3);
```

this fails with the error "method not supported by the object". So, I tried:

```
var onclickevent = string(btn.getAttribute("onclick"));
var subst = onclickevent.substring(2,3);
```

This fails again, when trying to cast to string with the message: "Object Expected"

How can I cast the getAttribute return value to string?

Comment: `String` has an upper-case `S`. Try with: `String(btn.getAttribute("onclick"));`

Comment: Please tell us what problem you're really trying to solve here and show us either the code or HTML that created the `btn` object and it's attributes.

Comment: What's is the output of console.log(onclickevent) in all three cases

Comment: What browser are you testing in?  `onclickevent.substring` works for me in Chrome 26.  http://jsfiddle.net/U9BYQ/

Comment: getAttribute() returns a string. You have got some other problem

Comment: @hop: I could as well return `null`, which might be a reason for the errors the OP is getting (the messages sound like IE, in other browsers they would be more descriptive)